# Why is this Prime number each on repeating

Tags: c++

I wrote a pseudorandom program in c++, it's basically a for loop with get the current number raising number 2 to it and subtracting by 1 and ending up with the prim number, but for some reason when my program hits the 32 number it repeats the prime number, how do I fix this repeating issue?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    for (int number = 1; number <= 35; number++)
    {
        int num = pow(2,number);
        int prime = (num - 1);
        cout << "Number: "<< number << " = " << prime <<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output:

```
Number: 1 = 1
Number: 2 = 3
Number: 3 = 7
Number: 4 = 15
Number: 5 = 31
Number: 6 = 63
Number: 7 = 127
Number: 8 = 255
Number: 9 = 511
Number: 10 = 1023
Number: 11 = 2047
Number: 12 = 4095
Number: 13 = 8191
Number: 14 = 16383
Number: 15 = 32767
Number: 16 = 65535
Number: 17 = 131071
Number: 18 = 262143
Number: 19 = 524287
Number: 20 = 1048575
Number: 21 = 2097151
Number: 22 = 4194303
Number: 23 = 8388607
Number: 24 = 16777215
Number: 25 = 33554431
Number: 26 = 67108863
Number: 27 = 134217727
Number: 28 = 268435455
Number: 29 = 536870911
Number: 30 = 1073741823
Number: 31 = 2147483647
Number: 32 = 2147483647
Number: 33 = 2147483647
Number: 34 = 2147483647
Number: 35 = 2147483647
```

Comment: off topic: A quick performance note on `int num = pow(2,number);`. `pow` is an expensive tool when all you need to do is `int num = number * number;`. It's great when you want the a number to the power of a fraction, say 0.72 or 1.67, but with a whole number you're almost always better off multiplying.

Comment: Don't use `std::endl` unless you need the extra stuff that it does. `'\n'` starts a new line.

Answer (score 5):

I'm guessing you're on a 32 bit machine, `2^32` or `33` or `34` will all overflow a 32 bit `int`.

You need a "bigger" type.

Comment: on 64-bit machine `int` is most probably 32 bits too

Answer (score 1):

As you are working with large primes recommended to use an unsigned type such as unsigned long long. In addition, you can use below to improve performance:

```
    unsigned long long num = 1;
    //in for loop
    num = num * 2;
```

Also, use of words prime and pseudorandom are confusing, may be you should say pseudo prime? Because somebody can be misguided that your algorithm will generate primes. Obviously in the list you generate there are primes (e.g. 31) and non primes (e.g 255). Mersenne primes are subset of primes that also happen to be 2^n - 1, not all of (2^n- 1) are primes.